# Create daily push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the Firebase console we can set a specific time and date when will our notification will be push. But is there a way that we can set it daily? For example it will send every Monday, Wednesday and Friday or everyday?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Push campaigns with Firebase Notifications **can be sent now or later (scheduled).**

You could probably switch to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), use their HTTP API and then build a cron script to trigger your notifications automatically on these days.

Or switch to a more mature product like Parse Server, Batch.com or anything else as they usually provide that daily/weekly/monthly recurring push notifications feature.

Comment: It's been 2 years, has anything changed?

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan nothing changed, Firebase Console is still very basic when it comes to push notifications scheduling. You can send "Now" or "Later" but you can *not* setup a recurring (daily) scenario. You can still play with Firebase Functions to setup a cron with this https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron and then trigger the notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging API.

Contrary to Firebase, Batch.com provides a way to schedule daily recurring notifications, see https://batch.com/doc/dashboard/push/timing-delivery.html#_recurring.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing a cron job.

Comment: UPDATE: You can set up the daily recurring FCM notifications now.

Answer (score 15):

Recurring messages are available in FCM now. May be helpful to someone.

[image: Daily]

[image: custom]

Comment: is there a way to do this programmatically ?

Comment: its not working. Its working nonsense. Once per user for this message. So every user just take the message once. What the daily do i dont know. There is a problem with this.

Comment: @vitralyoz I have the same feeling, do you have any solution to send daily per user?

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to schedule functions to run at specified times, use
> functions.pubsub.schedule().onRun() This convenience method creates a
> Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic and uses Google Cloud Scheduler to trigger
> events on that topic, ensuring that your function runs on the desired
> schedule.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions